# Receiving "curl: (3) Illegal characters found in URL" in a Linux Script

Tags: linux, bash, curl

I'm currently working on a script that reads in several hundred IP addresses listed line-by-line in a file. The script is supposed to take the IP addresses and then output the IP address and its longitude and latitude to a new file. However, whenever I try to run the script I received multiple "curl: (3) Illegal characters found in URL". I've been troubleshooting it for a couple of days, and so far I've come up with nothing. Can anyone put me in the right direction to figuring out the problem?

Thanks in advance for any help.

This is the script I'm using.

```
#!/bin/bash

cat ipCheck.txt | while read line

do

curl "https://api.ipstack.com/"$line"access_key=9c04ea7631a32590cac23eb27ec6c104&foraat=1&fields=ip,latitude,longitude"

done >> locations.txt
```

I'm currently using a test text file with 10 IP addresses. It is as follows

```
101.249.211.209

102.165.32.39

102.165.35.37

102.165.49.193

103.27.125.18

103.3.61.193

103.78.132.4

104.143.83.13

104.143.83.8

104.149.216.71
```

Comment: Thank you for the tips! I've edited it to reflect what you suggested.

Comment: You're welcome. Is the double-spacing in both the script and the data what you have or is this a cut&paste problem?

Comment: It's just a cut & paste problem. In the file it's all single-spaced.

Comment: Also see [How to use Shellcheck](http://github.com/koalaman/shellcheck), [How to debug a bash script?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/155551/56041) (U&L.SE), [How to debug a bash script?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/951336/608639) (SO), [How to debug bash script?](http://askubuntu.com/q/21136) (AskU), [Debugging Bash scripts](http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_02_03.html), etc.

Comment: `bash -x yourscript` is another good place to start -- the trace-level log it generates would be a useful addition to your question, if it doesn't make the issue immediately obvious (if that trace log contains `$'\r'` sequences, f/e, you know your input file or your script has DOS newlines).

Answer (score 0):

Nothing jumps out as being wrong.  Have you tried commenting out your curl line and running the loop with something like:

```
cat ipCheck.txt | while read line

do

#curl "https://api.ipstack.com/"$line"access_key=9c04ea7631a32590cac23eb27ec6c104&foraat=1&fields=ip,latitude,longitude"

echo "\"$line\""

done >> locations.txt
```

This should help to locate an extra space or something strange with the formatting.

If it isn't the formatting in your file, you could try:

```
cat ipCheck.txt | while read line

do

curl "https://api.ipstack.com/${line}access_key=9c04ea7631a32590cac23eb27ec6c104&foraat=1&fields=ip,latitude,longitude"

done >> locations.txt
```

This should give the same result, but you could have something strange going on with your environment.

Comment: `printf '%q\n' "$line"` is more useful than the `echo`, as the `printf` formulation goes to more effort to make nonprintable characters visible. See also the APPLICATION USAGE and RATIONALE sections of the [POSIX spec for `echo`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/echo.html), likewise recommending `printf` instead for nontrivial use cases.

Comment: `declare -p line` is another way to display the contents of the variable named `line` unambiguously. (`declare -p` also shows that variable's type, making it clear whether it's an environment variable, an array, or another special type that bash recognizes).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy good catch! In fact i my case I get a `$'B07RK1C4LD\r'` additional `\r` that causes the same problem!

Comment: Sounds like your file has DOS newlines (CRLF) rather than UNIX ones. `line=${line%$'\r'}` inside the loop will remove them, or of course tools like `dos2unix` will do the same.

Answer (score 0):

According to a previous comment a solution is to remove any additional character like the carriage return `\r` and checking using `printf`:

```
while IFS= read -r line; do
    # fix `\r` at end
    line=$(echo ${line} | tr -d '\r')
    printf 'Downloading %q\n' "$line"
    ./download.sh $FOLDER $line
done < "$DS"
```